# Database storage for iOS app similar to instagram

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, ios6

im currently working on an app that is similar to instagram (just for the experience) and i was wondering what kind of database would work best for this kind of app. I understand that most databases require a different language to learn and i'm completely fine with that, but which is the best for this? The app has photos all on a stream, profiles for each user, and comments on the photos. Would MySQL be the best choice or SQLite or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram runs on **PostgreSQL 9.0** (+ pgBouncer as connection pool). Give it a try!